# ReactJS.NET and it's performance on .NET MVC Razor

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, reactjs, razor

According to this site right here: http://tech.oyster.com/using-react-and-jquery-together/, React.JS doesn't suit well when paired with JQuery.

I'm concerned on the fact that Razor with React.JS might hinder React's great performance (like mentioned above). Do you guys have proof to approve or disprove this theory? I'm thinking it's better to just go all React.JS rather than integrate it with Razor to perform better.

Comment: Given that MVC is server side and React is client side, there will be no performance issues from combining them

Comment: i think similar

Comment: I mean, by combining Razor with React, they're both client side, I guess?